# reset token not working on production, but works locally in laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel

Locally I can reset a password with the default password/reset/{token}, but on live it errors saying token is invalid. If i comment out on Illuminate/Auth/Password/PasswordBroker.php then it works.

```
    if ( ! $this->tokens->exists($user, $credentials['token']))
    {
        // return PasswordBrokerContract::INVALID_TOKEN;
    }
```

I have had this on a couple of different sites now. Not sure what the deal is.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if anyone else ran into this situation. I modified the ResetsPassword.php file in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth. In my .gitignore I had /vendor and thus it wasn't copied over.

**You should not touch files in the vendor directory**. A user on Laracast pointed this out. Instead you should extend these methods. The reason is simple, if you do "composure update", you may lose your modifications.